# ng-bootstrap.github.io 's modal is not working with bootstrap3 css

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I am not able to figure it out, when i use bootstrap 4 with ng-bootsrap then the modal is displaying, but with bootstrap 3 it is not displaying modal

Answer (score 1):

This is expected since ng-bootstrap is only supporting Bootstrap 4 as indicated in the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and its [package.json](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/5856a75ace90c7323d073f1a9838560016bbb5d4/package.json#L48).

I would highly encourage you to start with Bootstrap 4 at this point as Bootstrap 3 is no longer maintained.